# IIS: What username do I use to read inetsrv\config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis

I have the code below for an aspx webpage to try and list all the running processes on an Azure VM IIS ASP.NET.

The following error comes up:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Filename: redirection.config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostAdminManager.GetAdminSection(String bstrSectionName, String bstrPath) at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.GetSectionInternal(ConfigurationSection section, String sectionPath, String locationPath) at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.ApplicationPoolsSectionCreator() at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory) at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.WorkerProcessCollectionCreator() at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory) at pages_test_generic_default.fEnumerateWorkerProcess() at pages_test_generic_default.pages_test_generic_default_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

From:
[Received 'Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions' when using web app manage task in Azure Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67538262/received-cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions-when-u) I thought I should add a Windows User so the webpage can read the **C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config** folder.

Questions:

1. What is the name of the user I should add when I right-click C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config and choose **Properties/Security/Edit/Add** User?
2. Is this a correct overall approach?

TIA
Mark

Code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.Administration

Partial Class pages_test_generic_default

 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Sub pages_test_generic_default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    fEnumerateWorkerProcess()

End Sub

Private Function fEnumerateWorkerProcess() As Boolean

    Dim bld1 As New StringBuilder

    Dim manager As ServerManager = New ServerManager()

    With bld1

        For Each proc As WorkerProcess In manager.WorkerProcesses
            .Append("WorkerProcess found: {0}", proc.ProcessId)
            .Append(vbTab & "|--AppPool : {0}", proc.AppPoolName)
            .Append(vbTab & "|--ProcGuid: {0}", proc.ProcessGuid)
            .Append(vbTab & "|--State   : {0}", proc.State.ToString())

            For Each appDom As ApplicationDomain In proc.ApplicationDomains
                .Append(vbTab & "+--ApplicationDomain Found: {0}", appDom.Id)
                .Append(vbTab & vbTab & "|--AppDomPhysPath: {0}", appDom.PhysicalPath)
                .Append(vbTab & vbTab & "+--AppDomVirtPath: {0}", appDom.VirtualPath)
            Next
        Next

        Response.Write(.ToString)

    End With

End Function

End Class
```

### **UPDATE 1:**

I followed the recommendation below by @samwu but the following error came up:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostElement.get_Collection() at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetCollection(String collectionName, Type collectionType) at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.WorkerProcessCollectionCreator() at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory) at pages_test_generic_default.fEnumerateWorkerProcess() at pages_test_generic_default.pages_test_generic_default_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

This was after adding permissions as suggested:

[image: Permissions]

### **UPDATE 2:**

I followed the second recommendation below by @samwu but the following errors came up:

Setting 1:
[image: Setting-1]

Setting 2:
[image: Setting-2]

Setting 3:
[image: Setting-3]

I also tried changing the user to IUSR and that also had no effect.

Comment: The user account you should use is typically from Local Administrators group of that IIS machine. Don't mess up with NTFS settings otherwise.

Comment: 1) If you set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) then Visual Studio can point out problems like not returning a value from a function. 2) You shouldn't really be using Response.Write like that - instead, put the text into a control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the name of the user I should add when I right-click C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config and choose Properties/Security/Edit/Add User?

The group you should add is `IIS_IUSRS`, this built-in group has access to all the necessary file and system resources so that an account, when added to this group, can seamlessly act as an application pool identity.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Please see Update 1 above in the original question—as an error still appeared.

Comment: You can try this way to solve this error: Application pool > Advanced Settings > Identity > Custom account, set your website to "Applicaton user (pass-through authentication)". If it still doesn't work, change IIS_IUSRS to IUSR.

Comment: Thanks again Sam. Please see Update 2 above in the original question.

Comment: You can try adding the administrator's account and password in the custom account.

Comment: Sam's "You can try adding the administrator's account and password in the custom account" suggestion worked. Thank you very much Sam. Much appreciated.